# why do i get a segmentation fault while casting void pointer to integer pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
using namespace std;
void* fun(int);
int main()
{
     int i;
     cin>>i;
     int *t = (int *)fun(i);
     if(!t)
         cout<<"null value\n";
     else cout<<*t<<"\n";
     return 0;
}
void* fun(int i)
{
     if(i==0)
         return NULL;
     else return (void *)i;
}
```

Getting segmentation fault on line cout<<*t<<"\n"; (while dereferencing) for all values other than 0

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: `(void*)i` isn't the address of `i`, it's the _value_ of `i` cast to a `void*`.  Such a pointer doesn't point to anything.

Comment: C-style casting in a C++ program should be considered a red flag that you're doing something wrong. And very, very seldom do you need to use `void*` pointers in C++. What is the real problem you try to solve? Why do you need `void*` pointers? Why is the function returning a values casted as a pointer?

Comment: What value do you expect it to print?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Actually it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void * fun (int i)`

This isn't the same `i` from main, rather a copy of it from a different location solely within the scope of this function `fun`. Using it outside the function scope through its address will result in undefined behavior. So, pass-by-reference instead and it will take the same `i` from main

`void* fun(int &i)`

Second thing is casting an integer to `void *`. This is converting an integer to address location and dereferencing it causes UB again.

`return (void *)&i;`

Will return the address can be casted back to `int *`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude along with passing by reference it won't

Answer (score 3):

With

```
return (void *)i;
```

you return the ***value*** of `i` as a pointer, but that value isn't a pointer in itself and therefore it can't be dereferenced.

You should simply cast it to the correct type, and print it as it is:

```
cout << reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(t) << '\n';
```

Comment: not only the cast is problematic, the `void*` returned from the function is dangling

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Not really dangling but just a value that is an invalid pointer (as the function doesn't really return a pointer).